# Batch Class when parent is created then child should get created

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

I have requirement When account is created then contact should get created and linked to that particular account.
Can we write batch class for it, i have written a Batch with Trigger

```
trigger ChildCreation on Account(after insert, before Delete) {
    
    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
           ESRT_Batch_Tour_Email_Creation b = new ESRT_Batch_Tour_Email_Creation(Trigger.new);
           Database.executeBatch(b);
    }
```

================================

Batch Class

```
global class ESRT_Batch_Tour_Email_Creation implements Database.Batchable <sObject> {
    
    List<Account> acc;
    
    public ESRT_Batch_Tour_Email_Creation (List<Account> acc{
        
        this.acc = acc;
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc){
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Tour_Date__c,Tenant__r.Name,Broker__r.Name,(Select id,Property__r.Name From Contact) from Account Where ID IN: acc';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account> batch) {
        List<Contact> c = new List<Contact>();
  
        for(Account a : batch){
            
                if(t.Tour_Date__c < date.today()){
                   Contact con = new Contact();
                    con.Account = a.Id;
                    
                    c.add(con);
                 
                }
            }
        }
        insert c;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        //Do Nothing.
    }
}
```

Can we write all logic in batch class only ????

Comment: Batch classes cannot execute by themselves. They always require some code in order to execute.

Comment: you have some issues in the execute - `t` is not defined; `con` insert will fail without a `LastName`

Comment: Hi Guys, Pls ignore that T and lastname I just want to know that can we write all  logic in batch class only because i need to write one scheduler for batch class's to schedule it but as i know it wont work if I call batch class in schedule as it wont get the account id , Please help... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you can definitely accomplish that without using batch class.

If you want more details you will have to be more specific:

- How can we know what kind of Contact records we need to create?